# Creating bufferedimage only saves the Panel background and not the stuff drawn on it

Tags: java, swing

I have a JPanel object called `drawPanel`. I draw various things like rectangles on it and when I try to create a bufferedimage and save it as following, it only saves a blank image with just the background color and not the rectangles drawn onto the frame.

```
BufferedImage image = createImage(drawPanel);
File outputfile = new File("MyImage.jpg");
try {
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}



public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {
    int w = panel.getWidth();
    int h = panel.getHeight();
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = bi.createGraphics();
    panel.print(g);
    return bi;
}
```

Kindly help me fix this problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Maybe using `panel.paint(g)` in addition to `panel.print(g)` will solve your problem

Comment: @AlexColeman: I'd actually think that `printAll(g)` would be better -- if he wanted to draw child components too.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels That sounds like it might be better, don't have a compiler open so I'm just taking a stab at it so he can try :P

Comment: @AlexColeman: I do know that print is better than paint when drawing components to an image as per [the tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/gui.html).

Comment: @AlexColeman `print` and `printAll` are preferred in these cases as they don't utilize double buffering

Comment: How does `drawPanel` work?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Good point, it looks like either should work, but there might be cases where printing is handled differently so `printAll` is likely better. Either way though, shouldn't `print` and `paint` both show any rectangles being drawn? `printAll` includes children, but that shouldn't be necessary if the component has no children

Comment: No, replacing `panel.print(g);` with  `panel.printAll(g);` doesn't work either.

Comment: Should I post my entire code?

Comment: *"Should I post my entire code?"*   No!  Post an MCVE as I advised in the first comment.

Comment: Oh man...I don't know how to break it up. It's a top-down design. So, every function is important. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### A little hackery with `Robot`

Simply replace your method `createImage` with my one. :-)

```
public BufferedImage createImage(JPanel panel) {
    //Get top-left coordinate of drawPanel w.r.t screen
    Point p = new Point(0, 0);
    SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(p, panel);

    //Get the region with wiht and heighht of panel and 
    // starting coordinates of p.x and p.y
    Rectangle region = panel.getBounds();
    region.x = p.x;
    region.y = p.y;
    
    //Get screen capture over the area of region
    BufferedImage bi = null;
    try {
        bi = new Robot().createScreenCapture( region );
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyPaintBrush.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    return bi;
}
```

[image]

[(Credit to this dude)](http://www.camick.com/java/source/ScreenImage.java)

Comment: This is by far the greatest help I've ever had on this site. I can't thank you enough Gary. You are awesome. :)

Answer (score 3):

This `Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) drawPanel.getGraphics();` is your problem.  Calling `print`, `printAll` or `paint` will wipe clean anything that was painted to the component using `getGraphics`.

The short answer is, never use it.  The long answer is, create a custom component, that extends from something like `JPanel` and override it's `paintComponent` method and perform ALL your custom painting within in it, when it's called.

See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details

Comment: Oh man...I spent all day writing this code...:( Can you please make small modifications in the existing code?